# How to fill a column of a pandas dataframe with an amount of digits?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_df1': [1,2,3,4],
                    'Name_df1': ['John', 'Alex', 'Alan', 'Marie'],
                    'Cod_job_df1': ['10151444', '20555', None, '40']})
```

I need the items in the 'Cod_job_df1' column to have a total of eleven digits. So I made the following code:

```
df1['Cod_job_df1'] = df1['Cod_job_df1'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(11))
```

This code was working perfectly. However, when I tested in a dataframe that has a column 'Cod_job_df1' equal to None, the error code and the message appears: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zfill'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), it will ignore null values by default:

```
df1['Cod_job_df1'] = df1['Cod_job_df1'].str.zfill(11)
```

output:

```
   ID_df1 Name_df1  Cod_job_df1
0       1     John  00010151444
1       2     Alex  00000020555
2       3     Alan         None
3       4    Marie  00000000040
```